# How to add QOS to Local Computer Policy with Powershell

Tags: powershell, script, shell-script, group-policy, qos

I have this code and it works but it makes a domain GPO policy and not a local one.  How do i get it to make it local?

```
#Create QOS for RDP Session
#Create a new Group Policy Object (GPO) that will be applied to the LocalHost that contain the computer objects.
#The value "Teams client - QoS" can be modified to fit your needs or naming standards
New-GPO "Local Computer Policy"  -Name "MSTSC" -Comment "QoS for Agents."

#Create Registry Value for Teams client Audio QoS in the "Teams Client - QoS" GPO
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "MSTSC" -Key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\QoS\MSTSC" -ValueName "Application Name", "DSCP Value", "Local IP", "Local IP Prefix Length", "Local Port", "Protocol", "Remote IP", "Remote IP Prefix Length", "Remote Port", "Throttle Rate", Version -Type String -Value "mstsc.exe", "0", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "-1", "1.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to put it in GPO but i was able to add it to the Registry

```
# Setup QOS on MSTSC session

# Works but doesn't show up in GPO Editor
#reg import .\MSTSC.reg

# Works but doesn't show up in GPO Editor
# Invoke-Command {reg import .\MSTSC.reg *>&1}

# Works but doesn't show up in GPO Editor
$StartParams = @{
FilePath = "$Env:SystemRoot\REGEDIT.exe"
ArgumentList = '/s','.\MSTSC.reg'
Verb = 'RunAs'
PassThru = $True
Wait = $True
}
$Proc = Start-Process @StartParams

If ($Proc.ExitCode -eq 0) { Write-Host 'Success!' }
Else { Write-Host "Fail! Exit code: $($Proc.ExitCode)" }

Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

As for this..

> 'makes a domain GPO policy and not a local one'

this is by design. There are no cmdlets for local GPO native in PowerShell so, either you have to write this yourself, or use this module

[PolicyFileEditor:](https://github.com/dlwyatt/PolicyFileEditor)

See this article on it's use: [How to manage Local Group Policy with Powershell](http://brandonpadgett.com/powershell/Local-gpo-powershell)

> This module can be used to manage your local policies, but it can also
>   be used to get the policies from Policy templates. An example would be
>   the policy templates shipped with Security Compliance Manager. If you
>   also want to set a baseline for your Local policies, you can use this
>   module to compare your live policies to the ones in the templates. It
>   is then very easy to go back and make a single change if a policy
>   changes. In the screenshot below you can see the output of
>   Get-PolicyFileEntry for a SCM Windows 10 User Policy.

Comment: That is a good article but i tried it and it didn't work for me.
See this article on it's use: How to manage Local Group Policy with Powershell